# Overwriting cells with external data table

Tags: excel

I have a complex workbook full of formulas linking back to a set of tabs at the beginning which contain the source data.

Currently that data is stored as a static set of data. I want to replace it with a dynamic external connection. Problem  is, when I load up the table it "helpfully" shunts the existing static data to the side, and all the formulas in the workbook "helpfully" update to reflect that- so they point to the old data in the new cells, not my new table!

Is there any way to either

A) overwrite the cells rather than inserting extra extra columns

B) Long shot- temporarily Excel updating formulas?

I think that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10684976/excel-2010-replace-a-table-by-an-external-connection-without-impacting-other-sh?rq=1) is similar to mine, but has no useful advice for my situation - I don't want to and probably can't manually update every formula range.

Thanks.

Comment: a few questions: 1) are you trying to do this with just the connection or with VBA?  2) are you going to keep the static data, or totally replace it?  3) Do the formula(e) exist in the location where the table will go or are they reading data from the table?

Comment: 1. I'd like to avoid VBA if I can. 2.The static data should be deleted and replaced entirely. 3. The formulae read from the table/static data.

Comment: I've got a solution for way B - the find/replace "=" with a symbol, then find/replace back trick. But if anyone does know a more elegant way to freeze formulae updates that would be welcome.

Comment: Just discovered (I think...) that if the static table is fully deleted no extra columns are added. It seems that it will insert rather than overwrite only when data is present. Will confirm and post as an answer to my question - is that correct StackOverflow procedure?

Comment: Incidentally, the MSDN wording implies not like my solution - [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobjects.add) - says that it inserts "therefore" data willnot be overwritten.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimenting it turns out the inserting of extra columns only takes place if data is present in the cells you are going to overwrite.

So deleting the data (NOT the cells) and then loading the query to the now clean area will work fine- formulae in the rest of the workbook will continue to link to the table.